# C++ increment std::atomic_int if nonzero

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I'm implementing a pointer / weak pointer mechanism using `std::atomic`s for the reference counter (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671308/220918)). For converting a weak pointer to a strong one I need to atomically

- check if the strong reference counter is nonzero
- if so, increment it
- know whether something has changed.

Is there a way to do this using `std::atomic_int`? I think it has to be possible using one of the `compare_exchange`, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` uses atomic reference counters, you know. You could always check the source.

Comment: what does the "know whether something has changed" part mean?

Comment: Whether it was nonzero before == whether it was incremented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the definition `std::atomic<int> ref_count;`

```
int previous = ref_count.load();
for (;;)
{
    if (previous == 0)
        break;
    if (ref_count.compare_exchange_weak(previous, previous + 1))
        break;
}
```

`previous` will hold the previous value. Note that `compare_exchange_weak` will update previous if it fails.

Comment: shouldnt ref_count.load() be in the for loop? I might be wrong, since I have really hard time thinking in atomic ops way. :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl `compare_exchange_weak` takes `previous` by reference and  updates it, so there's no need to do another `ref_count.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
bool increment_if_non_zero(std::atomic<int>& i) {
    int expected = i.load();
    int to_be_loaded = expected;

    do {
        if(expected == 0) {
            to_be_loaded = expected;
        }
        else {
            to_be_loaded = expected + 1;
        }
    } while(!i.compare_exchange_weak(expected, to_be_loaded));

    return expected;
}
```

Comment: It seems unnecessary to go ahead with the compare_exchange if you've already decided not to change the value.

Comment: @ymett I agree with you but I am somehow unsure, as I would else base my decision on whether to increment or not on two different states of `i`.

Comment: You only need to decide once. Once you've made the decision (in the `if`) you're finished.