# How can I do automatic memory management in C?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

In C memory allocation/deallocation done by `malloc` and `free`.

In C++ memory allocation/deallocation done by `new` and `delete`.

There are some solutions in C++ for **automatic memory management** like:

- Smart Pointers.
- RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization)
- Reference counting and cyclic references
- ...

But how can I do automatic memory management in C?

Is there any solutions for **AUTOMATIC** memory management in C?

Is there any guidelines or something like that for C?

I want when I foget `free` a block of memory:

- My code doesn't compile

-- or --

- Memory automatically deallocated

And then I say: ***Oh, C is better than C++, Java and C#.*** :-)

Comment: Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799825/smart-pointers-safe-memory-management-for-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may use a [Boehm garbage collector library](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Comment: It is a great reference for memory management methodology in C

Answer (score 2):

As [answered by Juraj Blaho](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6835765/841108), you can use a garbage collection library, such as the [Boehm conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/), but there are other ones : [Ravenbrook's memory pool system](http://www.ravenbrook.com/project/mps), my (unmaintained) [Qish GC](http://starynkevitch.net/basile/qishintro.html), [Matthew Plant's GC](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~maplant2/gc.html), etc...

And often, you can write your own [garbage collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) specialized for your use case. You could use in C the techniques mentioned in your question (smart pointers, reference counting), but you can also implement a mark & sweep GC, or a copying GC.

An important issue when coding your GC is to keep track of local pointer variables (to garbage collected data). You could keep them in local `struct` and chain them together.

I strongly suggest to read more about GC, e.g. the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/). The algorithms there are useful in many situations.

You could even customize your GCC compiler (e.g. using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) to add checks or to generate code (e.g. code to scan local variables) for your particular GC implementation. Or you could use some pre-processor (e.g. [GPP](http://www.nothingisreal.com/gpp/)) for that

In practice, Boehm's GC is often good enough.

Notice that liveness of some data is a whole-program property. So it better to think about GC very early in the design phase of your software development.

Notice also that detecting reliably [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) by static source code analysis is in general impossible ([undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem)), since it can be proven equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Answer (score 1):

For linux, I use valgrind. Sure, the original reason for why valgrind was build was to debug your code, but it does a lot more.  It will even tell you where potentially erroneous code could be in a non-invasive way. My own command line of choice is as follows.

```
# Install valgrind. Remove this line of code if you already have it installed
apt install valgrind
# Now, compile and valgrind the C
gcc main.c -Werror -fshort-enums -std=gnu11 -Og -g3 -dg -gdwarf-2 -rdynamic -o main
valgrind --quiet --leak-check=yes --tool=memcheck -Wall  ./main
```

Hope this helps. ~ Happy Coding!